# Is there a way to eliminate Google Play Books / Newsstand?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, delete

I've never used Books or Newsstand, and I'm continually running out of space. Is there a way to just delete these apps?

Android 4.1.2
Kernel 3.0.31-889555

Comment: What phone do you have, and what Android version are you using?

Comment: @DanHulme Sorry about that, added the info

Comment: If you go to *Settings→Apps*, select the "All" tab, scroll to the apps in question, and open their entry: Does it have a button to disable them? If not, it might be labeled "uninstall updates", and should be renamed "Disable" after you did that. With some luck, it's not grayed out then, here's the "push sequence": "Delete Cache", "Clear Data", "Disable". Done. If it is grayed out, all that's left is root and some "Bloatware remover", as indicated by [Lucas' answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/71467/16575).

Comment: @Izzy Thanks, I did just that. I hope I didn't break anything in the process :-)

Comment: Glad to read! I've just made it a full-fledged answer with additional details you might want to "accept", as it solved your issue :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Android 4.0, it is possible to "disable" apps without root. However, not all apps can be "disabled": some (pre-installed) [system-apps](/questions/tagged/system-apps) are protected against this. Still, it's always worth a try if you don't want to root your device:

1. Go to Settings→Apps
2. Select the "All" tab
3. Scroll to the apps in question, and open their entry
   Here you see either a button labeled "Disable", or one labeled "Uninstall Updates". If the latter is there, tap it: this will uninstall all the updates this app received during the time you already used the device. Now the "Disable" button should be visible in its place.

   - Is it "grayed out"?

     - Tap "Delete Cache", then "Clear Data". This will remove all cache files the app might have created, all its data, and its configuration.
     - Still "grayed out?" Then this app is "protected", you cannot "disable" it without root.
   - Otherwise: Tap it. This will disable/freeze the app.

These actions are reversible: You can always re-visit the apps entries here, and push the button again (it will be labeled "Enable" then).

If you could not deactivate an app this way, all that's left is root and some "Bloatware remover", as indicated by [Lucas' answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/71467/16575). Apart from *Titanium Backup*, there are several other "root-apps" which can do that – though *Titanium* is a great choice, as it also provides the means to do full backups and more. If chosing this path, make sure to *freeze* apps first to check for side-effects: As with above steps, a "freeze" is revertible – a "remove" is not (at least not easily).

Also see our [bloatware](/questions/tagged/bloatware) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/bloatware/info), which will give you / point you to more information.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Your device need have `root`. Search for `make root on my device (put here the device model)`. After having done root on your device, download Titanium Backup and write backup your apps and after delete. Sorry for my english.

Comment: I'll give that a try